# Setting up an associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
var mydata = [];

$.each(divs, function(idx, val){

var dID = $(val).attr("id");
                mydata[dID] = new Array();
                mydata[dID].push({'newproperty':"newvalue"});          
  });
```

This gives me results like this:

```
25465: Array[1]
0: Object
newproperty: "newvalue"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I want it like this:

```
25465: {
    newproperty: "newvalue"
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: JS doesn't have "associative arrays". it has arrays, and objects. You're getting exactly what you want. an array of objects.

Comment: Just use an object? `mydata[dID] = {key: 'value'};`.

Comment: @MarcB This is true. But theorethically one could "abuse" an array to be associative as you can attach arbitrary key/value pairs to it. In the end a plain object is what most people want.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a hashtable.  Unfortunately JavaScript isn't robust as say a language like Java, but there are still ways to accomplish what you are asking for.  Take a look at this [link](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html), I think you may find the answer there.

Answer (score 4):

> I want it like this

You've put in an unnecessary extra level of indirection.

```
// Create a blank object
var mydata = {};

$.each(divs, function(idx, val){
    var dID = $(val).attr("id");
    // Add/overwrite a property on that object with the name from the
    // variable dID, and the value being a new object with the properties
    // shown -- I assume those properties are just examples, since as
    // given they're identical on each pass...
    mydata[dID] = {'newproperty':"newvalue"};
});
```

Since you're not using the `Array` features of arrays, don't use an array, just use an object (`{}`). Since your goal is to have keys like `25465` refer directly to objects, don't create an array within the array/object, just assign to that key.